# Which front brake discs for CITROЁN C4 I HATCHBACK 1.6 HDI

Tags: brakes, part-identification, citroen, citroen-c4

I am wondering which brake discs to order for my Oct 2005 Citroen C4 Coupe Diesel (Berline). When I am searching I find both 283mm and 266mm models.

I am considering this set of discs and pads:

440.3106.20 brake discs

23599.190.1 brake pads

Would this be sufficient for the replacement or do I need additional parts for an easy replacement.

In terms of tooling, which Torx bit would be suitable to unscrew the brake disc (is it T55/T50)?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Why not ask these heavily model-specific questions on a Citroen forum instead of a general mechanics page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the size of disc matching those already fitted to the vehicle.

If the vehicle has the smaller discs and you want to move to the larger ones, then you shopping list will most likely include pads, discs, calipers and the caliper support bracket. Possible and has been done often on many vehicles...